# How to print more than one QStrings on QtextEdit

Tags: qt

Lets say we have a variable called `X` and we do some operations on it. now for printing it on the `QtextEdit` I want to print it like this `cout` on console:

```
cout << "The value of X is " << X << endl;
```

But the `setText` function only prints out a `QString` not both "the value of ... " and `X`.

Comment: cout does not know about QString, try QString::toLocal8Bit() or QString::toStdString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTextStream.html) to write data into a `QString` similar to `cout`:

```
int X = 42;

QString str;
QTextStream out(&str);
out << "The value of X is " << X << endl;

qDebug() << str;
```

Output:

```
"The value of X is 42
"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this in the following way:

```
QString text = QString("This is my value: %1").arg(x); // x can be either number or string
textEdit->setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "x" is an integer, for example, you can convert that number into a string and concatenate that with the introducing string like that:

```
QString myText = "This is my value: " + QString::number(x);
```

If x=5 this will give you this string:

```
This is my value: 5
```

You can now assign `myText` to your QTextEdit with `settext`.